# How i access a video from the menu in electron?

Tags: menu, electron

I'm learning Electron and i try to Pause,Play,Stop from a menu in my app ,but i don't know how to access the video from the menu .

```
let menuTemplate = [
  .......,
  {
    label: 'Video Controls',
    submenu: [
      { label: 'Pause', click() {mainWindow.webContents.on('media-started-playing',()=>document.querySelector("#video").pause()) } },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { label: 'Play', click() { console.log("Play") } },
      { type: 'separator' },
      { label: 'Stop', click() { console.log("Stop") } }
    ]
  },
  .......
let menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)


let tray = null

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    ........
  })
```

But when i tried it says mainWindow is not defined.
What i need to know if it is posible to access the video which i have from the menu and how?

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: @isherwood ,sorry i'm new ,i will try my best the next time,i changed it i think now it's better.

Comment: You'll need to define `mainWindow` in the global scope (like you define `tray`). Use `let`, not `const`. Remove the `const` definition from `createWindow`, just assign: `mainWindow = new BrowserWindow`.

Comment: Your title has the same three words in it. Did you see the guidance in [ask]?

Comment: @snwflk thanks it works, in final i use IPC to send a message to the renderer to pause .....